# How to develop nav bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to develop navigation bar in CSS. I am very new to CSS but I tried some way in my react/type script application. Below is my expectation.

[image: Navigation Bar]

In the above image, left side project name and right side company logo. In between I need dropdown which has two options. I tried as below.

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div id="header">
            <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", backgroundColor: "#f1f1f1", padding:"20px 10px" }}>

            </div>
        </div >
    );
}
```

Which simply display small image with grey color. I am really trying hard to get this done. Can someone help me how can I write CSS and HTML for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need CSS + HTML implementation you can have a look at bootstrap Navbar for this. [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Your Logo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to add project name in left side and logo in full right. How can I make those changes? Above code works for me Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Niranjan godbole, I've changed code snippet accordingly. Please have a look.